# How JIRA and Subversion is integrated and how to use it?

Tags: jira

I spent some time in both JIRA website and here, but still couldn't figure out. I have background from ClearCase ClearQuest and RTC. e.g. in CCCQ integration, when a developer check-out a file, he can select a task/bug from CQ due to the integration.

I installed JIRA and Subvertion, and JIRA Subversion plugin. Now couldn't figure out how to achieve the same I do with CCCQ integration.

Please give me a step-by-step instructions. Thanks.

Jirong

Comment: What is the question? I don't understand quite... don't you know how to install?

Comment: I installed "JIRA Subversion Plugin", do I need to install this "Subversion JIRA Plugin"? https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SVN/Subversion+JIRA+plugin

Answer (score 3):

Here you go, from the Atlassian documentation: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Integrating+JIRA+with+Subversion

Comment: This document isn't very helpful to a new user like me. But finally I figured out as follows: 1. Add SVN repository from JIRA Add-ON --> Subversion Repository. 2. Add comments during SVN commit with the JIRA project key, e.g. DEMO-1. Now when view the issues in JIRA, I can see Subversion commits. Question: how does SVN repository linked to JIRA projects? let's say I have three JIRA projects and three SVN repositories (I added all in ADD-on without the same way), can't find a place to link to an actual JIRA project.

Comment: OK, got it, it's the JIRA key.

Comment: That document is just the user side. The admin install side is rather dated because Atlassian now recommends using FishEye to integrate with SVN instead of the original JIRA Subversion plugin. Well, actually they recommend using Stash and git but that's another conversation.

Comment: Can someone please eloborate how to link svn with Jira ? I have a SVN account and a jira account.  How is a svn account linked to a particular jira user account?